# Making android device authorized at new computer

Tags: android, terminal, adb

The screen of my android device is broken such that it can't be controlled anymore using touch and I'd like to access it via adb on my computer. Fortunately, when it was unbroken I enabled USB debugging. But now I'm using a new computer. On my new computer `adb devices` tells me that it's unauthorized. When I try to do something with adb I get the error message `error: device unauthorized. Please check the confirmation dialog on your device.` which I can't do because of the broken screen. But I still have my old computer where the phone is authorized. Is it somehow possible to tell the device via adb at the old computer that the new computer (it's also fine with me to do it for all computers) is allowed to access the device?

Comment: With `adb shell` you can open a shell at the phone. This helps you to backup stuff and maybe it's possible to do a few last things which have to be done at that phone.